# Using sed inside php script is causing unexpected T_STRING error

Tags: php, sed

I'm adding a line to my php script:

```
exec('sed -i 1i'MAILTO=""' /var/spool/cron/' '.$clientName.');
```

But it shows me an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/admin/myproject.pl/newclient/main.php on line 368

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/admin/myproject.pl/newclient/main.php on line 368
```

Comment: From the syntax highlighting that SO does alone, you can already see that there's a problem in your `exec()` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error says it quite well. You have a syntax error.

Perhaps this is what you wanted?

```
exec('sed -i \'1i MAILTO=""\'  /var/spool/cron/'.$clientName);
```

Comment: We are almost close, but sed needs these two dashes '' after -i.

Comment: What 2 dashes? Please show an example of what the line should look like (if you enter it manually and it works)

Comment: Something like this: sed -i '1i MAILTO=""' /var/spool/cron/client

Comment: Thank you. I'm testing it now :)

Comment: No problem. If it's correct, don't forget to accept my answer as correct (Click the green V under the vote number).

Comment: Sure. No problem. Just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Not working. I got an error: sed: can't edit /var/spool/cron/: this is not regular file. It seems that it's trying to edit /var/spool/cron instead of /var/spool/cron/client

Comment: It should be this: exec('sed -i \'1i MAILTO=""\'  /var/spool/cron/'.$clientName.'');